# Specify range as only selecting filled cells/ending at empty cell Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32, win32com

Is there a way, using win32com, to specify that Python only selects/copies/pastes/autofills/etc a range that stops when it reaches an empty cell?

i.e.
Range(A1:A%End)

Certainly open to xlrd library suggestions, but my entire script is already using win32com. Thanks for any tips folks!

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

source = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\source")
excel.Range("A:AA").Select()
excel.Selection.Copy()

copy = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\copy")
excel.Range("E:AE").Select()
excel.Selection.PasteSpecial()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last non-emtpy cell via

```
XlDirectionDown = 4
last = wb.Range("A:A").End(XlDirectionDown)
range = wb.Range("A1:A"+str(last))
```

The `XlDirectionDown` is an XlDirection enum item (`xlDown`), you can also get its value from COM by dispatching via EnsureDispatch:

```
xlApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
import win32com.client.constants as cc
XlDirectionDown = cc.xlDown
```

First line builds the type library for Excel for win32com, which makes constants available.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I've been having trouble inserting this into my code (edited in the OP). Any suggestions? Haven't had any luck switching up the constants...

Comment: For instance, I tried: source = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\source") last = source.Range("A:AA").End(XlDirectionDown)
range = source.Range("A1:AA"+str(last))  range.Select()

Comment: @Reb I hadn't noticed your questions. Did you end up figuring out how to make use of this?

Comment: Sure did. And then I used Select() in order to set my range:  excel.Range("A1:A1").End(XlDirectionDown).Select() // last = excel.Selection.Address.  This returns the last cell address as "$A$x", x being the row number. Pretty cool. You can then use it to set a range:  Range("$A$1:"str(last)), as you showed. Many thanks, @Schollii, as always.